# error while starting render on startup

Tags: openstreetmap, rendering, mod-tile

i have configured a tile server by following the [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/)

in the last step for starting the render automatically on startup
if i start the render as below vars.sh is missing

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/renderd start
root's password:
/etc/init.d/renderd: line 33: /lib/init/vars.sh: No such file or directory
```

What is have missed in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/lib/init/vars.sh` is a file provided by the `initscripts` package. This is a standard package installed on every Ubuntu and Debian system. The file contains various default values for init scripts.

According to your other posts you are using openSUSE but the instructions on switch2osm are written for Ubuntu. This isn't recommended. In other words it means that you will have to look at the `/etc/init.d/renderd` init script and determine if it really needs to include `/lib/init/vars.sh`. Maybe it doesn't need these default values at all or you can fix it by setting them manually at the corresponding positions.

Comment: thanks.. but i searched in openSUSE i am not getting the vars.sh file.. is thier any alternative for the openSUSE

Comment: If there is no vars.sh file then openSUSE uses an alternative mechanism for supplying default values to init scripts. As I already wrote in my answer, you probably don't need this file. It will just initialize some variables with default values which you can add manually to the renderd script, if required at all.

Btw. is there some specific reason you are using a different distribution than the recommended one?

Comment: i will try to do that. Yes our company use SUSE

Comment: it is working after commenting the line.. #. /lib/init/vars.sh